# NodeJS MySQL Query in .forEach() seems to not execute / execute only once

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to write a little script that reads an xml-file and then imports the data I fetch into a MySQL-Database. The fetching works fine, but the inserting is a problem. I've worked with the `.forEach` to stay asnyc which helped me a lot and worked fine until I needed to insert the Data. When I tried to execute the "INSERT"-Query outside of the 'Loops' everything works fine, but as soon as I try to execute it inside of one it just inserts everything once and then stops. Also the `console.log()` message inside the `connection.query()` doesn't get executed, even though no error gets thrown.

This is my code:

```
console.log("Running import!");

//Import necessary modules
var fs = require("fs"); 
var config = require("./config");
var mysql = require("mysql");
var path = require("path");
var xml2js = require("xml2js");
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : config.mysql.host,
  user     : config.mysql.user,
  password : config.mysql.password,
  database : config.mysql.db
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) { //throw error
    console.error(err.stack);
    throw err;
  }else{
    console.log("Succesfully connected to the database!");
    // Get Folders in Folder and iterate through every of them
    var dirs = getDirectories(config.misc.path);


dirs.forEach(function(dir, index){
    var file = config.misc.path + "\\" + dir + "\\" + config.misc.xml_name;
    // read xml file of that directory
    fs.readFile(file, function(err, data){
        parser.parseString(data, function(err, json){
            if(err) throw err;
            json.resultset.forecast.forEach(function(forecast, index){
                forecast.parking_house.forEach(function(ph, index){
                    var ph_id = ph["$"].id;
                    ph.estimate.forEach(function(estimate, index){
                        var value = estimate.value[0]["_"];
                        var time = estimate.timestamp[0]["_"];
                        //console.log(time);
                        connection.query("INSERT INTO lb_data.estimates VALUES (DEFAULT,'23:00:00', 213, 44);", function(error, results, fields){
                            if(error) throw error;

                            //Printing %
                            var perc = (index / dirs.length * 100);
                            console.log("Scanned and imported " + Math.round(perc) + "% of the files");
                        });
                    });
                });
            });

        });
    });


});
}

  });


/**
 * Gets the direcotries in a directory
 * @param  {string} srcpath the source path of the directory you want to scan
 * @return {void}
 */
function getDirectories (srcpath) {
  return fs.readdirSync(srcpath)
    .filter(file => fs.statSync(path.join(srcpath, file)).isDirectory())
}
```

Already a big thanks in advance!
PS: Be ensured that the data in config.json is fine, I've tested that outside  the loop, so that is not the problem ....

Comment: .query is async. By the time the first insert is over the .forEach is over as well.

Comment: @yBrodsky how could i fix this ? Also: I thought that the forEach would allow me to do exactly that, sorry then this is a real bad mistake by me :/

Comment: You could create the query and INSERT everything at the end of your loop. Only 1 insert. How many records are you trying to insert?

Comment: About 63.000 cumulated, so this doesn't really make sense I think ... good idea though

Comment: Could I simply run a synced function that runs the query instead of the query directly ?

Comment: Since you have a lot of nested loops, why don't you do them all and store the values in an array of objects. Once you finish with all the loops, make an async.eachSeries with this array of objects you just created and insert the records one by one. http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries

Comment: This should work, I will try it as soon as possible, thanks!